# How to know JSON list including a specific key?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this database.

```
Order_id    Properties
  #        {"insurance":{"order":{"vat":5.1,"hhMass":" ....
  #        {"price_sms":0,"price_packaging":0}
```

If users did buy insurance the `properties` would have this value

```
{"insurance":{"order":{"vat":5.1,"hhMass":" ....
```

If not `properties` would be like this

```
{"price_sms":0,"price_packaging":0}
```

I would like to query all order with insurance

> PostgreSQL 11.4 (Debian 11.4-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu,
> compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

You can check the top-level keys using `?` operator

```sql
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE properties ? 'insurance';
```

[Postgres JSON Functions and Operators docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

> Does the string exist as a top-level key within the JSON value?